BitBucket pipeline run builds sequentially
I have BitBucket Pipeline that runs Terraform,
so need to run builds sequentially - next build should wait for previous build to complete
How is it possible to set?

I am assuming you are asking for a feature just like GitlabCI's resource_groups. If that is so, I beg you rephrase the question because it is somewhat confusing.
